# How can I use Custom Xml / User-Defined Tags in .pptx /.pptm so PowerPoint 2013 won't wipe it?

Tags: c#, xml, vba, powerpoint, openxml-sdk

I need to embed custom data in a .pptx that I generate, so that it can later be uploaded and have the images in the doc updated by my code.

I've tried a couple of methods now, and done lots of looking. I've found a couple of answers quite similar to this, but their solutions haven't worked for me - though perhaps I've just implemented them wrong. (links at the bottom)

The methods I've tried are:

1) Storing the custom data in an ExtendedAttribute:

```
//OpenXmlDrawing = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing

// there's only one image per slide for now, so I just grab the blip which contains the image
OpenXmlDrawing.Blip blip = slidePart.Slide.Descendants<OpenXmlDrawing.Blip>().FirstOrDefault(); 

//then apply the attribute
blip.SetAttribute(new OpenXmlAttribute("customAttributeName", null, customAttributeValue));
```

Doing so, the custom attributes would be wiped as soon as "Enable Editing" was turned on in PowerPoint 2013.

2) Store data in a a CustomXmlPart - this seems to be the generally agreed upon method from a few other posts.

So pretty much this is where I've ended up after multiple variations on this method:

```
public class CustomPropertyClass
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public string PropertyValue { get; set; }
}

private static void AddCustomPropertyToPart(string propertyName, string propertyValue, SlidePart slidePart, PresentationPart presentationPart)
{

    var rId = GenerateNewRelationshipIdForPart(presentationPart);
    CustomXmlPart customXmlPart = slidePart.AddNewPart<CustomXmlPart>("application/xml", rId);
    var customPropertyObject = new CustomPropertyClass { Id = rId, PropertyName = propertyName, PropertyValue = propertyValue };

    // serialize wwXmlProperty object & write that xml to the CustomXmlPart
    var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(customPropertyObject.GetType());
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    serializer.Serialize(stream, customPropertyObject);

    var customXml = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(customXmlPart.GetStream()))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(customXml);
        streamWriter.Flush();
    }

    // write CustomXmlElement into commonSlideData

    OpenXmlElement openXmlCustomElement;
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new MemoryStream()))
    {
        sw.Write(customXml);
        sw.Flush();
        sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        OpenXmlReader re = OpenXmlReader.Create(sw.BaseStream);

        re.Read();
        openXmlCustomElement = re.LoadCurrentElement();
        re.Close();
    }

    Slide slide = slidePart.Slide;
    var commonSlideData = slide.GetFirstChild<CommonSlideData>();
    var commonSlideDataExtensionList = commonSlideData.GetFirstChild<CommonSlideDataExtensionList>();
    commonSlideData.InsertBefore(openXmlCustomElement, commonSlideDataExtensionList);
}
```

It seems like it is being preserved through the 'Enable Editing' being turned on now. However as soon as I actually make an edit and save it, the changes are gone.

I'm using OpenXmlSDK 2.5 Productivity Tool to confirm the xml is in there or not. Here's an example of the presentation with the custom xml in it:

[image: Custom Xml in Productivity Tool]

As you can see, there's also a CustomXml item10.xml a couple levels higher. That also disappears as soon as changes are saved.

---

Links to other similar issues:

[Why does my custom XML not carry over to a new version of a DOCX file when Word saves it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341845/why-does-my-custom-xml-not-carry-over-to-a-new-version-of-a-docx-file-when-word)

http://openxmldeveloper.org/archive/2010/10/26/59361.aspx

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f1683cbe-d662-465a-978b-36277bb476e5/powerpoint-deletes-relation-of-customxmlpart-to-slide?forum=oxmlsdk

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/issues/127

---

**EDIT:** I've now also tried using UserDefinedTags:

```
private static void AddCustomPropertyToPart(string propertyName, string propertyValue, SlidePart slidePart, PresentationPart presentationPart)
{

    var rId = GenerateNewRelationshipIdForPart(presentationPart);

    TagList tagList = new TagList();
    Tag tag = new Tag() { Name = propertyName, Val = propertyValue };

    tagList.Append(tag);

    var userTagsPart = slidePart.AddNewPart<UserDefinedTagsPart>(rId);

    userTagsPart.TagList = tagList;
}
```

Which added the tags appropriately, but when I saved the presentation, once again they were gone.

I also tried using running a VBA Macro to add the tags to the base report template:

```
Sub AssignSlidesChartToolTypes()

    Dim ChartToolType As String

    For i = 1 To Application.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count

        With Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(i)
            ChartToolType = InputBox("Enter Chart Tool Type for Slide " & i)

            With .Tags
                .Add "chartToolType", ChartToolType
            End With
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

To use these, I had to save it as a .pptm file, but even then, they aren't preserved after making edits.

Comment: Via VBA or COM automation, you can add Tags (string data) to any presentation, slide or shape. These tags are preserved when presentations are edited. You might want to look into how tags are stored in the presentation's XML with an eye toward generating your own tags directly in the XML.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg thank you for the suggestion. I just tried using these tags two ways, I tried first with openXml, just adding a UserDefinedTagsPart to each slide. Unfortunately that was not preserved after editing. I also tried using VBA and running a macro which would add a tag to each slide, then I saved that as a .pptm, and unfortunately those tags were also not preserved (I did check that they were added to the tag list using another macro).

Comment: @SteveRindsberg you can see the edit at the bottom of the question for the code snippits of what I tried with tags

Comment: @Jnoteldim Can you post the VBA you used to add tags then describe precisely what you did next that caused the tags to disappear?  I've used tags extensively in PPT for 20 years or more and have never had them disappear.  I'm very curious to learn what might make this happen.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg the code's at the bottom of the question :)  ;For example I edited the text in a textbox on one slide & deleted a couple of other slides. then all the tags were gone - even on slides I didn't touch.

Comment: If you put your VBA macro in a different file and make sure your report file is the active one before running the code, you won't have to save the report file as a PPTM.  As to the tags disappearing, I'm mystified, I'm afraid.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg ah good to know about the macros. Yeah  I've tried everything I can find now. What we've done to get it working for now is to just override some "Title" properties in the nonVisualDrawingProperties objects. Would still like to find out a way to do it properly though.